# React Query use custom hook with useQuery on click event

Tags: reactjs, react-query, react-custom-hooks

I have a button that when the customer click it I need to fetch data from my database, for this I use React Query and I encountered a problem where I tried to use custom hook inside event handler which is not possible, I'm stuck on figuring out how to use it

this is my custom hook

```
 export const useGuestInfo = () => {
  const { bookingId } = useSearchParams();
  const { isGettingGuestInfo, data: guestInfo } = useQuery({
    queryKey: [`guest`, bookingId],
    queryFn: (bookingId) => getGuestInformation(bookingId),
  });
  return { isGettingGuestInfo, guestInfo };
};
```

and this is my Event handler I'm trying to use

```
  const onGuestUpdate = () => {
    setUpdateGuestModal(true);
    searchParams.set("bookingId", bookingId);
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
    const { isGettingGuestInfo, guestInfo } = useGuestInfo();
  };
```

the error i'm getting is Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

how would you do it?

another question, do you always need to use useQuery() when trying to fetch data from api or database? or you can do it in normal functions too? i'm new to programming :)

Comment: Do you want to re-fetch the data after setting bookingId? If that's the case then you can pass bookingId as param to useGuestInfo and useQuery will automatically get new data.

Comment: For your second question, no, it's not necessary to use useQuery. You can also use fetch (builtin library) or Axios to call the apis.

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar right now I can't fetch nothing because the custom hook is called inside an event handle and its against the rules, my problem is how can I implement it, that I will be able to fetch data by custom hook from inside an event handler

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the hook separate and conditionally call it only when bookingid is set.

The hook takes bookingId as parameter.
The `enabled` property will call the API only when bookingId is available.

**hooks.js**

```
export const useGuestInfo = (bookingId) => {
  const { isFetching: isGettingGuestInfo, data: guestInfo } = useQuery({
    queryKey: [`guest`, bookingId],
    enabled: bookingId !== null,
    queryFn: () => getGuestInformation(bookingId),
  });
  return { isGettingGuestInfo, guestInfo };
};
```

**App.js**

We declared useGuestInfo but it wont call the API until bookingId is not null.

onGuestUpdate method will set bookingId in searchParams and then `useGuestInfo` will be called.

```
const { bookingId } = useSearchParams();
const { isGettingGuestInfo, guestInfo } = useGuestInfo(bookingId)

const onGuestUpdate = () => {
    setUpdateGuestModal(true);
    searchParams.set("bookingId", bookingId);
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
};
```

I am not sure how `setSearchParams` works in your code but I guess you might replace `const { bookingId } = useSearchParams();` with `setSearchParams` data